# How to open url from script html file and run query in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, dom, window, onload

I am trying to open a url from script html file and run the query there. I am able to open the page but my query doesn work in there. Can someone have any idea  ?

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title></title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.location = "https://www.google.com/"
window.onload = function ()
    {
alert("Hello World!");
    }
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you can't do this for security reasons. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is some info about this. Tabs must have the same origin (port, protocol, host) to be able to interact with each other.

In your example problem is that u use `onload` in your CURRENT window, not in a new one. Here is correct code for `https://www.google.com` origin:

```
let windowProxy = window.open('https://www.google.com/');
windowProxy.addEventListener('load', () => {
    windowProxy.alert('Hello');
});
```

But if you want to make interaction between two tabs with same origin there are better descisions: [Broadcast API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) for example.

Comment: Hello @Alexey, thanks for the answer, appreciated.
I do not need to interact between tabs, just want to go to a website from the file and run some script in there after page load.
In your example alert is showing up before the page load.
Do you know how can I get over this ?

Comment: @AliDogan use `addEventListener`. I changed the answer

Comment: Hello @Alexey,
Sorry to bother but this time it doesnt work at all. ;(

Comment: You got some error? This code should work only in google.com. U can try to open console in dev tools there and run code in it. Or u have to change url in window.open

Comment: Hello Alexey, when I put the script in chrome console, it works. But then I save below code as html file and clik on it, it just open the page, doesnt run the script. I tried even opening in same page with _self optiont. :(

<html> 
<head> 
<title></title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<script> 
let windowProxy = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75472600/how-to-open-url-from-script-html-file-and-run-query-in-new-tab/75472917?noredirect=1#comment133163193_75472917');
windowProxy.addEventListener('load', () => {
    windowProxy.alert('Hello');
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>

Comment: I answered why in first sentence. You can't evaluate your js in other origin because of security reasons in modern browsers.

Comment: Old times gold times :) Thank you so much for your time Alexey :)